# Javascript constructor function

Tags: javascript, prototype

When trying executing the two following code blocks separately:
The first one:

```
function Hallo() {

}
var some_obj = {
    name: "Fred",
    age: 23,
}
Hallo.prototype = some_obj;
var obj = new Hallo();
obj.constructor;
```

And the second one:

```
 function Hallo() {

    }
    Hallo.prototype.name = 'Khanh';
    Hallo.prototype.age = 23;
    var obj = new Hallo();
    obj.constructor;
```

I got the result in firebug's console is "Object{}" for the first and "Hallo()" for the second.
While the second one is pretty simple to understand but the first one is really odd. Because as I know the constructor of the obj Object in the first one is still the same (that is Hallo() function).
However I got Object() function in result.
I really cann't understand why. Could you help me with it?
Thank you!

Comment: You're overwriting the entire `prototype` in the first example, but in the second you're only adding two new properties.

Comment: Yes, I know it, but the constructor is still the same, isn't it? I concern about constructor.

Comment: `constructor` is overwritten by the constructor of your object when you overwrite the *entire* prototype.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***The reason is:***

When you do `var obj = new Hallo();`, then

```
console.log(obj.constructor === Hallo.prototype.constructor); // true
```

In your first example, you assigned `Hallo.prototype` with a new object, whose `constructor` is function `Object` (`function Object(){...}`).

In your second example, the `Hallo.prototype.constructor` is still `function Hallo() {...}`

Comment: Thank xdazz, I did test you answer using firebug. and yes, it return exactly as you said. So if I do: var obj = new Hallo(), the constructor of obj is NOT really Hallo() function but always the Hallo.prototype constructor function. However, I read a book call Object Oriented Javascript, and it said: If I do: var obj = new Hallo(), then the obj Object is created by Hallo() constructor function. So it differ from you answer. Could you explain me about this confusion?

Answer (score 1):

prototype will get a reference that point to the constructor by default, int the first function you overwrite the prototype to some_obj, the constructor reference changes at the same time to some_obj's constructor reference --Object's constructor Object()